# How to get the Label Name on which i am currently on in Blogger?

Tags: blogger

How to retrieve the label name of the page I am currently on.
Lets assume that I am on [News](http://www.haywirelab.com/search/label/News) , I want to retrieve label name "News". How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<data:view.search.label/>` or `<data:blog.searchLabel/>`